# Пара векторов или вектор пар

Tags: c++, vector

Что будет производительней в общем случае: вектор пар или 2 вектора, где каждый содержит свой элемент?

Скорость нужна для операций: получение одного из значений пары по индексу, добавление пары в конец, удаление пары с конца.

Comment: Надежнее всего не гадать, а померять время. Вангую, что один вектор лучше, потому что манипуляций с кучей меньше...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрим ассемблерный код https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rZAAcJ

```
test1():
  mov rax, QWORD PTR b[rip]
  mov rdx, QWORD PTR a[rip]
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rax+20]
  add eax, DWORD PTR [rdx+20]
  ret
test2():
  mov rdx, QWORD PTR z[rip]
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rdx+44]
  add eax, DWORD PTR [rdx+40]
  ret
```

Как видно, у 2 векторов есть 1 лишняя операция (получение указателя на начало вектора). Аналогично и при записи. Поэтому один вектор пар выглядит быстрее.

Без тестирования всё это только предположения, но крайне сомнительно, что данный выбор на что-то *существенно*  повлияет. Выбирайте что лучше подходит по семантике.